# When i try to execute createSQLQuery() coming this exception Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name

Tags: hibernate

```
hql = "SELECT USER_CODE, USER_NAME, USER_SHORT_NAME, PRINT_NAME, USER_PASSWORD, REMARKS, RECORD_ACTIVE,"+
                        " INACTIVE_WEF, CREATED_BY, CREATED_ON, MODIFIED_BY, MODIFIED_ON " +
                        "(SELECT DESGN_NAME FROM MCDESIGNATIONMASTER WHERE DESGN_CODE = :DESIGNATION_CODE)TSUSERMASTER_DESIGNATION " +
                        " FROM MCUSERMASTER WHERE USER_CODE LIKE NVL(:USER_CODE,'%') AND USER_NAME LIKE NVL(:USER_NAME,'%')";
                System.out.println("hql----"+hql);
                Query query = session.createSQLQuery(hql).addEntity(UserMasterModel.class).setParameter("USER_CODE",roleMasterModel.getUserCode()).setParameter("USER_NAME", roleMasterModel.getUserName());
```

Comment: remove 3rd line - looks like you inserted it by mistake. Try to execute the script with sql client to verify it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You missed a comma after MODIFIED_ON, but it's difficult to see it without an SQL code indentation:
2. You can't mix column selects with query results. What if the second query returns more than one row.
3. You only use two parameters USER_CODE and USER_NAME, but your second subselect adds one more (DESIGNATION_CODE) and you never supply its value.
4. Since there is no correlation between those two queries I think this is what you must have:

   ```
   Query mcMasterQuery = session
       .createSQLQuery(
       "SELECT "+
       "   USER_CODE, "+
       "   USER_NAME, "+
       "   USER_SHORT_NAME, "+
       "   PRINT_NAME, "+
       "   USER_PASSWORD, "+
       "   REMARKS, "+
       "   RECORD_ACTIVE, "+
       "   INACTIVE_WEF, "+
       "   CREATED_BY, "+
       "   CREATED_ON, "+
       "   MODIFIED_BY, "+
       "   MODIFIED_ON "+
       "FROM MCUSERMASTER "+
       "WHERE "+
       "   USER_CODE LIKE NVL(:USER_CODE,'%') AND "+
       "   USER_NAME LIKE NVL(:USER_NAME,'%')"
       )
       .addEntity(UserMasterModel.class)
       .setParameter("USER_CODE", roleMasterModel.getUserCode())
       .setParameter("USER_NAME", roleMasterModel.getUserName());

   Query mcDesignationQuery = session
       .createSQLQuery(
       "SELECT " +
       "   DESGN_NAME " +
       "FROM MCDESIGNATIONMASTER " +
       "WHERE " +
       "   DESGN_CODE = :DESIGNATION_CODE" 
       )
       .addEntity(UserMasterModel.class)
       .setParameter("DESIGNATION_CODE", designationCode);
   ```